# How to get an APN profile certificate into the keychain

Tags: ios, xcode

My laptop/handset is set up and working for enabling our application to work with push notifications.
A colleague however is getting the "no valid aps-environment entitlement string found" upon installing the app with their setup.

I noticed that Xcode's Organizer is reporting an error for the Apple Push Profile saying "no valid signing identity" could be found (everything looks set up ok on the provisioning portal web page), and also noticed that on my machine in my keychain access in the "My Certificates" section there is a certificate for the Push. However on my colleague's machine they do not have this in their keychain access.

I presume its absence is the reason for the "no valid signing identity"? If so, how do they add it to their keychain? (I can't remember how it got there for me and can't readily find out from googling).

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to be I don't think, try this:

Check you have the necessary profiles on the device - go to the settings, then general, profiles, check your profiles are listed, especially the push profile of course. 
You can also check this from the Organizer section of XCode. In Organizer there are two sections that say Provision Profiles - one at the top left in Library (this is the profiles in XCode that you use to sign etc.) Also you will see a section call Provisioning Profiles for the device that is connected, this is the profile that is installed on the handset. 
If you don't have them installed on the handset you can download them from the provisioning portal website, then click on the Add button at the bottom of the Organizer window.

While in the provisioning portal you should also check that the Apple Push Profile includes the certificates:
- click on Provisioning on the left hand menu
- you'll see a list of your profile, select to EDIT the Apple push profile
- you'll see a certificates section, with a list of developers or testers etc. you have in your project, make sure the check box is checked for them.
- you'll also see a devices section, make sure the device you are testing on has been added.

If you have any old profiles in XCode or on the device delete them and download/refresh/install all the new profiles from the provisioning portal